# Importing root level files in @types module in a Create React App+Typescript setup

Tags: typescript, webpack, create-react-app, codemirror

I'm working on a project built with Create React App (not ejected), and I have both the codemirror and [@types/codemirror](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/codemirror) modules installed.

The way the types are set up is that it uses [namespace merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to augment the types to match how Codemirror adds functionality through addons.

For example, if you just do this:

`import {EditorConfiguration} from "codemirror"`

the default `EditorConfiguration` interface defined in `@types/codemirror/index.d.ts` doesn't have a `styleActiveLine` property

But if you do this:

```
import {EditorConfiguration} from "codemirror"
import "codemirror/addon/selection/active-line";
```

Contents of `@types/codemirror/addon/selection/active-line.d.ts`:

```
import * as CodeMirror from "codemirror";

declare module "codemirror" {
    ...
    interface EditorConfiguration {
        styleActiveLine?: StyleActiveLine | boolean;
    }
}
```

Then the interface `EditorConfiguration` WILL have the `styleActiveLine` property.

So all of the above works, 100%, and I was very impressed. BUT, when I try to import `@types/codemirror/codemirror-comment.d.ts`, then the typescript compiler outs the following error:

`Can't resolve 'codemirror/codemirror-comment' in 'project\src\editor-components'`

This only happens to the files are in the root of the module. Any idea what is happening here?

Other notes:

1) I also tried doing something weird with relative paths, like referring to this file as "codemirror/addon/../codemirror-comment". That didn't seem to work.

2) The typescript server does see it at some point, and offers the autocorrect, but the compiler doesn't seem to see it.
[image: Code]

Here's my tsconfig in case you're curious:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "es2016", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the full namespace/path

See how I import Axios here

[image]

I hope this works out for you

Comment: That doesn't work for me unfortunately, I think it has something to do with my typescript settings? Updated the main post with my tsconfig.json.

Comment: Do you have a public github repo I can use to troubleshoot?